# Unable to install r package inside django docker container

Tags: python, r, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a [web service](https://github.com/r08922129/webservice) by [cookie-cutter django](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html)

For some reason, I have to call R-script to response user requests. So, at first, I tried to add a R's Dockerfile into local.yml. (in the last section)

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: webservice_local_django
    container_name: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: webservice_production_postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: webservice_local_docs
    container_name: docs
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./webservice:/app/webservice:z
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    container_name: mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0
    container_name: redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: webservice_local_celeryworker
    container_name: celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: webservice_local_celerybeat
    container_name: celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: webservice_local_flower
    container_name: flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
  R:
    image: r_local
    container_name: r_local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/R/Dockerfile
```

And here is the ./compose/local/R/Dockerfile

```
FROM r-base
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("dplyr")'
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("xgboost")'
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("TSrepr")'
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("ggplot2")'
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("foreach")'
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("doParallel")'
```

But when I run `docker-compose -f local.yml up`
Some errors occurred

```
r_local         | Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
r_local exited with code 2
```

I googled it and found some [discussion](https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client/issues/19)
But it mentioned Rserve. I don't think I used it.
So I tried another way that installed R in the django container directly.

```
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django apt-get update
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django apt install r-base-core -y
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django apt-get install r-cran-quantre\
g
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django apt-get install r-cran-sparsem
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
dplyr")'
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
xgboost")'
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
TSrepr")'
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
ggplot2")'
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
foreach")'
sudo docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django Rscript -e 'install.packages("\
doParallel")'
```

Then, I got

```
E: Unable to locate package r-base-core
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-quantreg
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-sparsem
/entrypoint: line 45: exec: Rscript: not found
/entrypoint: line 45: exec: Rscript: not found
...
```

(many lines are ommited for clarity)

Is there any simple way to call Rscript in the django docker's enviroment? Many thanks.